# What is the difference of “Standing rules” of an organization and “Rules” of an organization?

Tags: differences, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences among ‘Rules’, ‘Standing Rules’, and ‘Bylaw’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/what-are-the-differences-among-rules-standing-rules-and-bylaw)

I recently received the articles of an organization (community club) which is captioned as “*Standing Rules*” of the organization. I don’t know why the word “Standing” is necessary before “Rules”?

Though the free encyclopedia defines “standing rules” as;

“Standing rules are regulations or rules that deal with the procedures and operations of a business or guidance of an institution or administration of a society and are adopted from time to time similarly as any other act of the deliberative assembly. Generally, the standing rules can be amended only by a majority vote."

I don’t understand why the word “Standing” is necessary before “Rules” when the organization and its rules were in place for a decade without any change.

Can you explain me the difference of “Standing rules” of an organization from “Rules” of an organization, and “The Articles” of an organization?

Comment: You are right in thinking it was strange when you said the organization and its rules were in place for a decade without any change. I would think the use of "standing" gives a feeling of temporariness.

Comment: Off topic AND duplicate? Voting to close.

Comment: @Jwpat7.Yah. I totally forgot that I had placed the similar question before thanks to my senility. I realized by tracking back my posts by your remark. Incidentally I received the same Club Rules yesterday from the community club I’m belonging to, which recurred the same question. I don’t know how to close this question. Can you close this?

Comment: @Kris: I'll vote to close, too, because it's a duplicate, but I don't find this "off-topic."  It seems a legitimate question about the usage of the word "standing". (No one voted to close the other question, and it even got two upvotes.)

Comment: Yoichi, if you like, you can delete this copy, or if that's locked out, flag it for deletion by moderator.